# How to check unicode characters in a if statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tamil

I want to check if a first character is a consonant and if second is a particular character in a word. The if statement does not work at all,

> ```
> if letters[i] not in [u'அ',u'ஆ',u'இ',u'ஈ',u'உ',u'ஊ',u'எ',u'ஏ',u'ஐ',u'ஒ',u'ஓ',u'ஔ'] and letters[i+1] in [u'ஃ']:
>     print "yes,case 1"
> ```

I am not able to find out a why. A similar if statement where i check if 1st character is a vowel and next is some other character works fine. But this does not work. I have tried both with "in" and "not in",

> ```
> if letters[i] in [u'க',u'ச',u'ட',u'த',u'ப',u'ற'] and letters[i+1] in [u'ஃ']:
>              print "yes,case 2"
> ```

both dont work. why is that?

Comment: Are you certain that the characters are in fact equivalent? What is does `print repr(letters[i]), repr(letters[i+1])` show? Is that strictly equal to `repr(u'அஆஇஈஉஊஎஏஐஒஓஔ')` and `repr(u'ஃ')`? Are any of these character *combined characters* consisting of 2 or more Unicode codepoints?

Comment: `u'\u0b94'` can be expressed as `'\u0B92\u0BD7'` as well.

Comment: actually அஆஇஈஉஊஎஏஐஒஓஔ and ஃ have a single codepoint only. But am not sure about u'க',u'ச',u'ட',u'த',u'ப',u'ற'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the codepoints for கசடதபறஅஆஇஈஉஊஎஏஐஒஓஔ all correspond to 1 only, i checked now [u'\u0b95', u'\u0b9a', u'\u0b9f', u'\u0ba4', u'\u0baa', u'\u0bb1\u0b85', u'\u0b86', u'\u0b87', u'\u0b88', u'\u0b89', u'\u0b8a', u'\u0b8e', u'\u0b8f', u'\u0b90', u'\u0b92', u'\u0b93', u'\u0b94']

Comment: @MartijnPieters I dont think the '\u0B92\u0BD7' representation of u'\u0b94' is used mostly. Am able to check for some other cases with similar statements, only for the  கசடதபற and other consonants in Tamil, this does not work.

Comment: I don't read tamil at all, all I did was check for `unicodedata.decomposition()` values. You'll have to carefully check your letters to make sure your codepoints actually match; combining codepoints like that are one way you can be tripped up.